# Циклический сдвиг в ГОСТ 28147-89

Tags: алгоритм

https://traditio.wiki/%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2_28147-89
Разобран пример по ГОСТу 28147-89. Всё понятно до момента сдвига.
B1 7F E0 85
сдвинули на 11 бит в сторону старших разрядов и получилось:
2F 8C FD 03
Объясните, пожалуйста, как здесь происходит сдвиг? В моём понимании сдвиг на 11 бит в сторону старших разрядов исходного выражения даёт FF 04 2D 8B. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При циклическом сдвиге число сворачивается в кольцо, и "выдавливаемые" биты не теряются, а вставляются "с обратной стороны".

Было (не забываем про реверс):

85 E0 7F B1== **1000 0101 111**0 0000 0111 1111 1011 0001

Делаем циклический сдвиг (т.е. просто отрезаем выделенные биты от головы и приставляем к заднице), получаем

0000 0011 1111 1101 1000 1**100 0010 1111** == 03 FD 8C 2F

Опять реверс - и получаем ровно то, что в статье.

Comment: Вы огромный молодец! Я бы сам не догадался. Спасибо большое